# partially commutative monoid

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ be a simple graph with vertex $I$ and edge set $E$. I am defining $M(G)$ to be the quotient of the free monoid $I^*$ on $I$ by the relations $ab=ba$ and $c^2 = 1$ whenever $\{a,b\} \notin E(G)$ and $c \in I$  is **arbitrary**.

I have the following questions about the monoid $M(G)$.

1. Is this monoid $M(G)$ well studied in the literature?
2. What are some algebraic combinatorics or general combinatorial significance of this monoid?

Thanks for your time and have a good day.

Comment: If you just make adjacent vertices commute you get what are called trace monoids or free partially commutative monoids.  They were studied by Cartier and Foata in the seventies in connection with combinatorics and there is now also a huge literature in automata and concurrency theory. I don't know why you are imposing the second relation which doesn't menton b

Comment: Usually one makes adjacent vertices commute but you can use complements.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I am interested in the case when both the given condition holds and not just the first commuting relation alone.

Comment: But then every vertex which is not connected to some vertex is an involution. So it seems to me you get a free product of a right angled coxeter group and a free monoid.

Comment: To follow-up on Benjamin Steinberg's comment, do you mean that for the path with vertices $a, b, c$ and edges $ab$ and $bc$, that $M = \langle a, b, c \mid a^2 = c^2 = 1, ac = ca \rangle$ (as a monoid)?

Comment: Dear all, very sorry. I have made some changes in the question. Kindly check.

Comment: With your changes, your monoid is in fact a group: $c^n = 1$ for some $n$ (depending on $c$) implies that $c$ has an inverse.  The object you've defined is called a graph product of finite cyclic groups.  As Benjamin says, these are called right-angled Coxeter groups if $n = 2$ for every $c \in I$.

Comment: @RobertBell but I am going modulo $c^n =1 \,\forall\, n \ge 2$ not for single $n$. So in my monoid $1 = c^2 = c^3 = \cdots$

Comment: If $c^2=1=c^3$ then $c=1$ and your monoid is trivial.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg Can you please explain, in a free monoid why $c^2 = 1 = c^3 $ implies $c = 1$?

Comment: If $c^2=c^3=1$ then $1=c^3=c^2\cdot c=1\cdot c=c$.

Comment: Nice. Now I understood completely. Thank you all. Some problem with my theory it seems. I will check.

Comment: Mark Sapir's comment to the closed duplicate of this question answers (1): **"It is called Right Angled Coxeter Group (RACG). Google it"**